# Properly assigning a function with arguments to a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two files:

**functions.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class funcs():
    def func1(entry):
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
```

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import functions as f

root = tk.Tk()

entrybox = tk.Entry(master=root).grid()
button = tk.Button(master=root, command=f.funcs.func1(entrybox)).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

In *main.py*, I have assigned the command *func1* with the argument *entrybox* to the widget *button*.
My intent is to have the *entry* argument represent an entry widget I want to manipulate.

This line of code is broken:

> button = tk.Button(master=root, command=f.funcs.func1(entrybox)).grid()

The problem is that when I run the program, the function is **called immediately** and does not get assigned to the button.

I am looking for a way to assign a function **with arguments** to a button in tkinter.

Comment: Also you have 1 more problem (other than the one outlined in the answers). You need to split `entrybox = tk.Entry(...).grid()` into `entrybox = tk.Entry(...)` and `entrybox.grid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function:

```
tk.Button(
    master=root,
    command=lambda: f.funcs.func1(entrybox)
)
```

Comment: You might want to add that OP's `entrybox = tk.Entry(...).grid()` is also incorrect. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) is the reasoning behind it

Answer (score 0):

Python recognizes the broken line of code as an immediate call, so you have to do lambda:

```
button = tk.Button(master=root, command=lambda: f.funcs.func1(entrybox)).grid()
```

and as far as I know that will get rid of the problem.